# How to remove .DS_Store in swift3

Tags: swift3, nsfilemanager

Hi here `commonPath` is my document directory path. I have to remove `.DS_Store` file in my directory.

In swift 2 I used below code it works fine

```
var imageNames = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(commonPath)

                if imageNames.count > 0
                {
                    imageNames.contains(".DS_Store") ? imageNames.removeAtIndex(imageNames.indexOf(".DS_Store")!) : imageNames[0]
                }
```

But I can't able to use the same code in swift 3.0

Xcode convert automatically above code to

```
imageNames.contains(".DS_Store") ? imageNames.remove(at: imageNames.index(of: ".DS_Store")!) : imageNames[0]
```

It shows error.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get document path using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` then do the following thing . Hope it will work.

```
let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

let commonPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(reportImageFolder)
let outPath = commonPath + "/"

arrImages = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: outPath as String)

  if arrImages.count > 0
   {
      arrImages.contains(".DS_Store") ? arrImages.remove(at: arrImages.index(of: ".DS_Store")!) : arrImages[0]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in swift 3:

```
var imageNames = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: commonPath)

if imageNames.count > 0 {
    if imageNames.contains(".DS_Store") {
        imageNames.remove(at: imageNames.index(of: ".DS_Store")!)
    }
}
// do something with imageNames[0]
```